# NPM dependency is not creating git submodule

Tags: npm, git-submodules, jshint

I'm running grunt.js. One of its dependencies is node-jshint which has the actual jshint files added as a submodule. (I'm using my own fork of node-jshint so that I can do some modifications to the jshint source).

If you npm install in grunt, it'll install node-jshint and it will also build the jshint submodule.

However, my package.json file is pointing to the url of my node-jshint fork rather than the npm version, and the jshint submodule never gets created.

It seems like when npm grabs dependencies normally, it's internally running git submodule update, but when it grabs dependencies via a URL, it never runs that command.

Is there anyway to force npm to run git submodule update when it install a dependency, like via package.json?

Comment: How could I accurately reproduce this?